# Page not found error when Trying to use Ajax on a Django Post LIKE DISLIKE functionality

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, django

I have a Django Post Like/Dislike feature in my App. The feature works amazing on its own. However when I add ajax to the Like/Dislike button the whole thing breaks giving me a Page not found Error

**Working Code without Ajax**

*Models.py*

```
class Post(models.Model): #title, slug, message, etc exist but not included here 
   likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='post_likes')

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('posts:single', kwargs={'username': self.user.username,
                                           'slug': self.slug})

def get_api_like_url(self):
    return reverse('posts:like_post', kwargs={'username': self.user.username,
                                         'slug': self.slug})
```

*Views.py*

```
class PostLikeToggle(LoginRequiredMixin, RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        slug = self.kwargs.get('slug')
        print(slug) #Prints the slug
        obj = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
        url_ = obj.get_absolute_url()
        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_authenticated():
            if user in obj.likes.all():
                obj.likes.remove(user)
            else:
                obj.likes.add(user)
        print(url_)
        return url_
```

*Template:*

```
<form action="{{post.get_api_like_url}}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if user in post.likes.all %}
    <button type="submit" name="post_slug" value="{{ post.slug }}" class="btn btn-link like_button">
        <img class="like_heart" src="{% static 'images/HEART.RED.png' %}" height="25px">
    </button>
    {% else %}
    <button type="submit" name="post_slug" value="{{ post.slug }}" class="btn btn-link like_button">
        <img class="like_heart" src="{% static 'images/HEART.png' %}" height="25px">
    </button>
    {% endif %}

</form>
```

*Urls.py*

```
url(r'^(?P<username>[-\w]+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/like_post/$', views.PostLikeToggle.as_view(), name="like_post")
```

- Everything above works perfectly

I added Ajax. **Below is my code after adding AJAX where I get the Page not found**

*Template* same as above

*Models* same as above

*Urls* same as above

*Views.py*

```
class PostLikeToggle(LoginRequiredMixin, RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        slug = self.kwargs.get('slug')
        print(slug)
        obj = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_authenticated():
            if user in obj.likes.all():
                obj.likes.remove(user)
            else:
                obj.likes.add(user)
            context = {
                "post": obj,

            }
            if self.request.is_ajax():
                html = render_to_string("posts/like_section.html", context, request=self.request)
                print(html) #This prints the html
                print(JsonResponse({"form": html})) #This prints <JsonResponse status_code=200, "application/json">
                return JsonResponse({"form": html})
```

*Added Script to base.html*

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".like_button").click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var slug = $(this).attr("value"); #I have tried console.logging slug it works
                $.ajax({
                    url : "{{post.get_api_like_url}}",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {"slug": slug, "csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}"},
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#like-section").html(data["form"]);
                        console.log($("#like-section").html(data["form"]));
                    }, error: function (rs, e) {
                        console.log("error");
                        console.log(rs, e);
                    }
                })
            })
        })
    </script>
```

> Terminal prints everything in the view with print and then gives the below
>
> : [24/Sep/2018 00:23:10] "POST
>   /posts/charlize/singes-boat-new-york/like_post/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
>
> Not Found: /posts/charlize/singes-boat-new-york/like_post/
>   [24/Sep/2018 00:23:10] "GET /posts/charlize/singes-boat-new-york/like_post/%3CJsonResponse%20**status_code=200**,%20%22application/json%22%3E **HTTP/1.1" 404 7845**

[image]

FYI: If I manually refresh the page the Like/Dislike toggle has worked

Comment: It looks like the URL you're POSTing to is returning html, when you're expecting JSON. If so, you need to fix it so that either the view for that URL returns JSON, or deal with the actual HTML response in your Ajax code.

Comment: @RobinZigmond could you show me in code. Doesn't `return JsonResponse({"form": html})` take care of that in the view

Comment: sorry, I missed that you had that. But on looking at the html more closely, i've realised that it's a Django error page, saying that it couldn't find the page requested. So there must be an error in your url setup - you should check this. (You've only shared one line of it.)

Comment: @RobinZigmond it works without the Ajax,What do you think the URL should be. Do you need the Post Detail Url to diagnose the issue

Comment: From squinting at that raw html, it appears that the url it is looking for is `/posts/charlize/singes-boat-new-york/like_post`. If that isn't the URL you expect, then you need to look at the value of the `post` template variable, in particular its `get_api_like_url` property. Are you saying that this precise URL is found if you access it directly, but not via the Ajax call? Are you sure it's the exact same URL? Since you're using class-based views, could it be that you've got a `GET` method for that route but not a `POST` one? Just trying to come up with ideas...

Comment: @RobinZigmond I have been trying to figure out what it could be. In the **non-Ajax** view when you call `get_api_like_url` through the `like` button. It goes to the `Redirect  view` as in it does something("like/dislike" toggle) and returns the post_detail(the same page the user was before). **When I do the Ajax** its supposed to just change the like/dislike div. Its currently not doing that. Do you think the  `/posts/charlize/singes-boat-new-york/like_post` should work on its own.(Currently its not )

Comment: _" its supposed to just change the like/dislike div"_. But ajax is meant to make a request to the server asynchronously, not just change the html on the client side.

Comment: @guillermochamorro he needs to involve the server to save or remove the like from the database @SamirTendulkar - having now looked in more detail, I believe the problem is that, in the Ajax version, what is `return`ed by your `get_redirect_view` method is a response object. When it should be the URL to be redirected to. Since you no longer need a redirect, in the Ajax case, I would try using a "normal" (non-redirect) view, which will do the database work and return the appropriate JSON response.

Comment: @RobinZigmond :) Looks like that's what I'll be doing all day

Comment: I'm not a Django dev, but the problem seems to originate from `obj = get_object_or_404()`. So when `self.request.is_ajax()` is `true`, are you sure the `post` has a valid data, particularly the `get_api_like_url` property? In the JS code, try `console.log()`-ing the `post` object.

Comment: @SallyCJ I am not sure how to console.log the `post` object as `post` is not a variable in the script

Comment: Maybe try `console.log( '{{post}}' )`.. or something like that. But you can actually inspect the jQuery's XHR/AJAX *request* (URL, data, etc.) via the `rs` variable in your `error` callback.

Comment: @SallyCJ I tried `console.log( '{{post}}' )` It worked it prints the `posts.title` like it should. The Question is half resolved. can you see the Answer and try to figure the other half

Comment: Try using *delegated* event handler: `$(".like_button").on('click', function( event ){ ... })` instead of using `.click()`.

Comment: @SallyCJ that did,'t help It does the same thing 1st part is asynchronous the second part is a page refresh

Comment: Sorry, I meant: `$(document).on('click', ".like_button", function( event ){ ... })` - i.e. attach the handler to the `document` instead of the `.like_button` elements that are *currently* on the page.

Comment: @SallyCJ awesome that worked you want to answer the question

Comment: @SamirTendulkar I'm glad it worked for you. Cheers! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are implementing the `get_redirect_url` method. Whatever that method returns us treated as a URL to redirect the browser to. The `JsonResponse` function returns an object with the response data. But since this is `get_redirect_url`, Django thinks that it is a string with the URL.

Instead, implement the `post` method and manually return a `HttpResponseRedirect` if it is a normal request, and the `JsonResponse` if it is a AJAX request.

Another thing: You are using the `LoginRequiredMixin` mix-in. No need to check for `user.is_authenticated` in the View.

```
class PostLikeToggle(LoginRequiredMixin, RedirectView):
    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        slug = self.kwargs.get('slug')
        obj = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
        user = self.request.user
        context = {"post": obj}

        if user in obj.likes.all():
            obj.likes.remove(user)
        else:
            obj.likes.add(user)

        if self.request.is_ajax():
            html = render_to_string("posts/like_section.html", context, request=self.request)
            return JsonResponse({"form": html})

        url = obj.get_absolute_url()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

Comment: I have no Django install here now, so its untested, but I added how it could be implemented to my answer.

Comment: Hey good news I just realized from `DISLIKE` to `LIKE` is Asynchronous However from `LIKE` to `DISLIKE` Its a Page refresh. Trying to resolve that. Do you think you know why that could be happening. If we figure that. This question is answered

Comment: Its actually the 1st operation is asynchronous. If I close and restart the browser the 1st operation is asynchronous. The second one is a page refresh

Comment: That happens, because you insert new HTML. The new `.like_button` element is not the same as the old one, so the Event Handler you registered on page-load with `$(".like_button").click(function (event) {` is forgotten for that one element, and doesn't catch the click anymore.

Comment: Is there a way to overcome that so that the code is 100% asynchronous

Comment: Just changed the script to include `$(document).on('click', ".like_button", function( event ){` that made the code 100% asynchronous